# Edit/Delete related entries from different controller, return to current page in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, controller

Let's say for example I got a school class with n students. I am looking for a way I am able to not just edit or delete a related entry, but redirecting back to it's origin page.

So if I am at view.ctp of school class XY (`cake/classes/1`) and want to edit/delete a listed student, I want to get back to this school class. But when I am on the index of the students (`cake/students/`), I want to be redirected to that page itself.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you thought about using ajax?

Comment: @Dave like your suggestion! maybe i will change it in future, but not as for now.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more "cake" way of doing this is:

```
    <?php
class UserController extends AppController {
    function delete($id) {
        // delete code goes here, and then...
        if ($this->referer() != '/') {
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

found in the book here: 
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html

Comment: it's the cake way of life! thanks, was searching for something like this!